# Borel measures and integration

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, borel-measures

Let $\mu$ denote a finite Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}$. What are
the following limits: $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(tx)d\mu(x)$
and $\lim_{t\rightarrow0}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f(tx)d\mu(x)?$ $f$ is
a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$ with compact support here.

Comment: What do you think they are? On what do you think they will depend?

Answer (score 1):

If "finite measure" means $\mu(\mathbb{R})<\infty$ or even if it means the measure of the compact support of $f$ is finite, then, since continuity of $f$ on a compact set implies boundedness of $f$, the dominated convergence theorem should be applicable.  Since $f$ is continuous, its limit at 0 will be $f(0)$, a constant that can be pulled out from under the integral.  The fact that $f$ is continuous and has compact support tells you what its limit at $\infty$ is.